# In cricket and football is it alright to refer to women as men?

Tags: names, grammatical-gender, political-correctness

I noticed when I was watching the match between England and Mexico in the Women's Football World Cup the other night, that the commentator would refer to a situation where the attacking side 'had a man over'. I also heard of one referring to a possibility of having to play 'a man-short up front'.

In Women's Cricket, they still have 'batsmen', 'last-man-in', and no doubt 'night-watchmen'. Somebody has to field at 'third man' etc.

Is this alright? Or are the commentary teams guilty of misogyny?

When is it ok to refer to a woman as a man, and when should she be a woman or a person?

Comment: Those are fixed expressions from the time these sports were played only by men, are they?

Comment: Point of fact: women's cricketers are actually *batters*. Apparently they prefer a stream of C B Fry/ fill it jokes to being either *batsmen* or *batswomen*

Comment: @TimLymington In that case they could adopt the motto of the chippy in our village who have a notice which says *well battered but never beaten*.

Comment: ?? Why should one refer to women as men ?  Perhaps I'm a bit daft, but I really don't see the problem, though I know that exaggerated gendre-correctness can reach astonishing heights, which I find quite amusing.  What would be the gender-correct person? A hermaphrodite?  That would be a pity.

Comment: It’s definitely not misogyny just based on that—calling a female player a batsman hardly constitutes hatred of the female sex. At most it's politically incorrect.

Comment: How about a "bowling a maiden over"?

Comment: @NeilW Good one, but I think you should just put the inverted commas around 'maiden over'. People who have not the benefit of cricket in their upbringing may be wondering what *bowling a maiden over* is all about.

Comment: @WS2 They may indeed. Like me. I would assume it meant running so fast past a young woman that you knocked her over in the process, but I suspect that’s not quite what it really means here. (The dictionary definition of _maiden over_ as “an over in which no runs are scored” doesn’t really make me any the wiser…)

Comment: A 'bowler' in cricket is the player who 'bowls' the ball at the batsman. (I suppose you knew that much). He bowls six times (called six 'balls') and then another bowler bowls from the other end. Each six balls is termed an 'over'. If the bowler bowls an entire over with no runs being scored off it by the batsman, it is known as a 'maiden over'. So 'bowling a maiden over' has nothing to do with felling a young lady to the ground, nor about presenting yourself in such a way as she is unable to forbear your charms.

Answer (score 2):

With the phrases "Thar/there she blows" and "How fast is she?" what gender is the whale/car?

Phrases like "had a man over," "a man-short up front," "batsmen," "last-man-in," etc., are some that have stuck and come naturally. If you'd like, you can think of "man" as a shorter way of saying "human" in instances like these where you're using "man" as the name/title of a position/situation.

Comment: The whole question of gender distinctions in occupational
and related names is sensitive,verging on explosive.

Answer (score 2):

Yes this is alright.  As an example, we set up the chess men on the board, including the queen.

Comment: True, but chess pieces are not real people.

Comment: But what if you have a set of anatomically correct, naked chess people?

Comment: @WS2 How would you tell which piece is which? When that hypothetical situation comes up, we'll deal with it then, same as usual.

Answer (score -1):

In english man can mean the male species but also the human species. As an example woman means human that causes grief/distress as in many other languages.

Comment: The first sentence is all right, but what in the world happened after that. _Woman_ does not mean anything like “human that causes grief/distress” in English or in any other language I'm familiar with. Where on earth did you get that from?

Comment: wo comes from woe. Same in the nordic languages except there it is female human causing grief/distress. I have seen the same in some other languages, but forgotten which.

Comment: No. The _wo-_ part in _woman_ does not come from _woe_. It has absolutely **nothing** to do with _woe_, which you could have ascertained easily by looking up the word’s etymology. _Woman_ is the Modern English descendant of Old English _wīfman_ (or _wīfmon_) meaning literally ‘wife-man’, with ‘man’ meaning (as it did originally) simply ‘human/person’. There is also no such relation in any Nordic languages, where the normal word for _woman_ is etymologically cognate to English _queen_, and the cognates of _wife_ are not combined with _man_ at all, though forms like _kvindemenneske_ exist.

Comment: More than 20 years ago I came across an explanation of the word for woman in several languages. Didn't realize it was a joke.